# Logging only insert, update and delete mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, logging

i need to make mysql to log only insert , update , delete queries  is that possible ?

i did manage to get it to auto generate logs adding the "log=C:\wamp\mysql\log\queries.log" line to the my.ini configuration file of mysql,
but it logs everything and soon it will fillout the disk

during days of research i did not found any solution
using  mysqlbinlog is not option for me and i cant set triggers for 3000 tables

Comment: So explain why mysqlbinlog is not a option to use?

Comment: i dont using binary logging

Comment: So... turn it on?

Comment: is it possible to enable mysqlbinlog  only on slave replica?